# ImportError: cannot import name game

Tags: python-2.7

I am getting the error - ImportError: cannot import name

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.7-py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 418, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.7-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.7-py2.7.egg/nose/importer.py", line 94, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/Users/rng/PycharmProjects/ex47/tests/ex47_tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ex47 import game
ImportError: cannot import name game`

Here's my directory structure for reference:
Within the folder I have two folders and two python files:
./ex47
 ./tests
 **init**.py
 setup.py

./ex47:
game.py
  **init**.py

./tests:
ex47_tests.py
  **init**.py

the ex47_tests.py looks like this:
from nose.tools import *
from ex47 import game

I have read and tried the export PYTHONPATH=. on the directory above to no avail. Thoughts?